# Adding multiple images to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider, slideshow

I'm new to Android programming. I'd like to make a very simple app where you can browse a few predefined images fullscreen. I tried the following tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager

Android is a bit complicated to me with the .xml files for resources etc. I thought XML was just to define the individual resources, but I realized they also act similarly to HTML pages when I want to create a view. I managed to display one image by replacing the second TextView "textView" by my ImageView in activity_screen_slide.xml.

But the problem is that it now it displays the same image with each page. How can I set a different one for each page? I tried to add multiple LinearLayouts with different images, but the app crashed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! Did my code solve your problem? I could add more details if you're still having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't have time to implement it yet. I gave the bounty to you because you seemed to put the most effort to it (and got the most upvotes, as well). I couldn't finish the project in time for other reasons, but I'll implement it when I can, and tell you if I encounter a problem. Thanks for the offer!

Answer (score 7):

To show a different image on each slide, you'll need to add some code that defines the correct image for each page. Since you're just trying to display a few predefined images, I'm guessing that you've already loaded the images into your project's drawable directory. With that assumption in mind, I'll walk you through the missing pieces in [the example you're following](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager).

If you haven't done so already, create your `ScreenSlidePageFragment` class, and modify the code to look something like this:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";
private int id; // resource id of the static image to display in this page

public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// Your program should call this to create each instance of this Fragment.
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int id) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_RESOURCE_ID, id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_RESOURCE_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
    // assign our image's resource id here
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    return view;
}
```

Because we want each fragment to display an image with a different resource id, I added a parameter (`id`) that you can pass to the fragment when you create it.

Now, we just need to make some minor changes to `ScreenSlidePagerActivity`. First, add a static array that contains the drawable image resources that you want to use. It should look something like this:

```
private static final int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
```

Finally, modify your PagerAdapter, so that `getCount` returns the size of your array, and `getItem` looks up the appropriate resource id for each page before creating each slide's fragment.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position < IMAGES.length)
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(IMAGES[position]);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you go about it. Also, make sure you are using an image loading library (like Glide) to avoid OutOfMemory crashes while loading images.

```
    public class ImagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ImagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6; //number of images you want to display
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
   }

    public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int position){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putInt("IMAGE_POSITION", position);
       ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
       fragment.setArguments(bundle);
       return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment_layout, container, false);
int option =           getArguments().getInt("IMAGE_POSITION");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
        Glide.with(this).load(imgs.getResourceId(SAUtils.getIndex(option) - 1, -1)).into(imageView);
        imgs.recycle();
        return view;


       }
        }

//in main activity
ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter();
pager.setAdapter(adapter);


//in resources.xml    
<integer-array name="options_icons">
        <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
        <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
        <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
        <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
        <item>@drawable/image_5</item>
        <item>@drawable/image_6</item>
    </integer-array>

//image_fragment_layout
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </FrameLayout>


        //main_activity_layout
               <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/main_app_gradient"
            android:paddingBottom="56dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt this code

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }
```

Then you pick one of your images according to the value of "position"

And this method needs to return your image count:

```
 @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add something like showcase view or a tutorial/intro view for your application with great UI and animation included, then you can use the gradle libraries for this purpose. It gives a proffessional touch to the app as well.

```
https://github.com/florent37/TutoShowcase
https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView
https://github.com/florent37/TutoShowcase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use android widget called View Flipper to Add dynamic or Static images with easy custom animations..Check this link for overview :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html